# Can a std::vector member variable be uninitialized (memory error)?

Tags: c++, memory, c++11, valgrind

This is an excerpt from source code of a larger simulation tool:

```
struct Foo {
  std::vector<int> v;
}

...

Foo* foo;

...

foo->v.resize(0);
```

Valgrind reports an `Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)` for the line of the `resize(0)`. The only explanation I have is that somehow the memory for a class `Foo` was allocated but never initialized, and thus the (default) constructor of `v` was never called (note that `Foo` does not provide a user-declared constructor).

Could anyone tell me if this could actually be the case (allocated-but-not-initialized) and why/how? If my explanation is wrong, do you have any other ideas? I tried searching SO for related questions but could not find the answer :-/

P.S.: I am using Valgrind 3.9.0 and GCC 4.8.2 with C++11 enabled. The full Valgrind message:

```
==967== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==967==    at 0x939751: std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >::resize(unsigned long) (stl_vector.h:666)
...
```

Comment: Where do you new Foo? Foo doesn't need a user-declared constructor.

Comment: So how are you allocating and initialising a `Foo`? You've only shown us the declaration of an uninitialised pointer. What does that point to when you try to access the vector?

Comment: It's `foo`. Also, if you don't provide compilable code, the question cannot be answered properly.

Comment: Well, it's *possible* that the memory is uninitialized (but that's probably not the case here -- the pointer itself is probably uninitialized, not the memory it points to). Consider: `Foo* foo = (Foo*)12345;`

Comment: I like how the answers resize their new vector to 0!

Comment: @NeilKirk well, I did just write an answer that has a defined behaviour. Imagine something super special, or if you want edit some super fancy code into my answer if it makes you happy ;)

Answer (score 8):

`Foo* foo;` does not construct an object `Foo`. It does only initialize the memory for a pointer to a `Foo` object.

You would not get the error message if you did:

```
Foo foo;
foo.v.resize(10);
```

or:

```
Foo* foo = new Foo();
foo->v.resize(10);
```

If you do actually not want to allocate memory that you have to manage you could as well use a smart pointer:

```
std::unique_ptr<Foo> foo(new Foo());
foo->v.resize(10);
```

Answer (score 2):

This is undefined behavior. And the result is everything dependent. Your program can execute normally, or get a seg fault on the same platform, same compiler etc.. So to avoid this always initialize pointer before using. 
In this case:

```
Foo* ptr = new Foo();
ptr->v.resize( 0 );
```